# Elasticsearch Sorting by Likes and Dislikes

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I've been struggling to express the current logic problem I'm trying to solve with Elasticsearch, and I think I have a good way to represent it.

Let's say I'm building out an API to sort Mario Kart characters in order of the user's preference. The user can list characters they like, and those they dislike. Here is the data set:

```
{character: {name: "Mario", weight: "Light"}},
{character: {name: "Luigi", weight: "Medium"}},
{character: {name: "Peach", weight: "Light"}},
{character: {name: "Bowser", weight: "Heavy"}},
{character: {name: "Toad", weight: "Light"}},
{character: {name: "Koopa", weight: "Medium"}}
```

The user inputs that they like `Mario` and `Luigi` and do not like `Bowser`. With Elasticsearch, how could I go about sorting this data for the user so the list is returned like so:

```
[Mario (+), Luigi (+), Peach, Toad, Koopa, Bowser (-)]
```

*Pluses and minuses in there for legibility.

This would return the user's top choices in front, the ones they are OK with in the middle, and the ones they don't prefer at the end. Having to use nested queries really trips me up here.

Evolving the query, let's say there's a team mode where each team is comprised of pairs of two, determined by the game in the following pairs:

```
[Luigi (+), Bowser (-)]
[Mario (+), Peach]
[Toad, Koopa]
```

How to I ensure that I don't filter out teams that contain `Bowser`, yet still weight the results so that it's like so:

```
[Mario (+), Peach]
[Toad, Koopa]
[Luigi (+), Bowser (-)]
```

Or, should `[Luigi, Bowser]` actually rank second?

I'm very confused about building complex queries like these in Elasticsearch and would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can just boost your relavance score by user's preference and sort by score then return just the name of the characters. The second part if there is a field that identifies which team a character belongs to then you can do a terms aggregation to bring the pairs together

Comment: Would you be able to post an example? I can post what my current query later tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your mapping, something along the lines of

```
GET /characters/_search
        {
   "sort":[
      "_score"
   ],
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "constant_score":{
                  "filter":{
                     "term":{
                        "name.keyword":"Mario"
                     }
                  },
                  "boost":2.0
               }
            },
            {
               "constant_score":{
                  "filter":{
                     "term":{
                        "name.keyword":"Luigi"
                     }
                  },
                  "boost":2.0
               }
            },
            {
               "constant_score":{
                  "filter":{
                     "term":{
                        "name.keyword":"Peach"
                     }
                  },
                  "boost":1.0
               }
            },
            {
               "constant_score":{
                  "filter":{
                     "term":{
                        "name.keyword":"Toad"
                     }
                  },
                  "boost":1.0
               }
            },
            {
               "constant_score":{
                  "filter":{
                     "term":{
                        "name.keyword":"Koopa"
                     }
                  },
                  "boost":1.0
               }
            },
            {
               "constant_score":{
                  "filter":{
                     "term":{
                        "name.keyword":"Bowser"
                     }
                  },
                  "boost":0
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

should work. 
PS: IF you have a nested mapping then surround the bool query with a nested query clause and adjust the field name paths. To return only the name field add _source clause before the query with path to name as value.

Comment: No need to explicitly sort by relevance. That's the default behaviour.

Comment: Just for my paranoia that ES may change defaults and break compatibility :)

Answer (score 0):

First off I gotta say - IMHO using Elasticsearch for this is major overkill. You should probably go with a much simpler in memory data structure for this calculation.

Assuming you do decide to implement this with Elasticsearch, I would do the following thing:

1) Represent each character as a document using this mapping -

```
PUT game/characters/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "name":{
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "weight": {
      "type": "keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

2) Each character will look like so:

```
PUT game/characters/boswer
{
  "name": "bowser",
  "weight": "heavy"
}
```

3) And then you can fetch them ordered by likes similiarly to how @sramalingam24 suggested. Note that the boosts must non-negative, so you'd need to "normalize" the likeability of the characters to a range above zero:

```
GET game/characters/_search
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "name": "Peach"
              }
            },
            "boost": 2
          }
        },{
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "name": "Mario"
              }
            },
            "boost": 2
          }
        },{
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "name": "Toad"
              }
            },
            "boost": 1
          }
        },{
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "name": "Bowser"
              }
            },
            "boost": 0
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Good luck!